# How to listen for a specific time in Java thread?

Tags: java, multithreading

I am creating multiple threads and I want each thread to listen for any new message in its BlockingQueue for 2 seconds and then die away. I am using the following code:

```
public class Main {
    public static void main(String[] argv) throws Exception {
        int capacity = 10;
        BlockingQueue<String> queue = new ArrayBlockingQueue<String>(capacity);

        ArrayList<String> names = new ArrayList<String>();
        names.add("Apple"); names.add("Banana"); names.add("Mango");
        HashMap<String, Worker> workermap = new HashMap<String, Worker>();
        for (String name: names) {
            Worker a_worker = new Worker(queue);
            a_worker.setName(name);
            a_worker.start();
            workermap.put(name, new Worker(queue));
        }
        queue.put("Hello ");
    }
}

class Worker extends Thread {
    BlockingQueue<String> q;

    Worker(BlockingQueue<String> q) {
        this.q = q;
    }

    public void run() {
        try {
            long start = System.currentTimeMillis();
            long end = start + 2*1000;
            while (true) {
                String x = q.take();
                if(System.currentTimeMillis()>=end){
                    System.out.println("No new message since two seconds, killing thread " + this.getName());
                    Thread.interrupted();
//                    break;
                }
//                if (x == null) {
//                    break;
//                }

                System.out.println(x + "from " + this.getName());
            }

        } catch (InterruptedException e) {
        }
    }
}
```

I expect the output to be like:

```
Hello from Apple
Hello from Banana
Hello from Mango
No new message since two seconds, killing thread Apple
No new message since two seconds, killing thread Banana
No new message since two seconds, killing thread Mango
```

But I just get `Hello from Apple` and then nothing after that. The process keeps on going without any further output. Besides using the timer to kill the thread, I have also tried checking if the queue element is null, but no success. Where am I going wrong?

Comment: Use `BlockingQueue.poll(2, TimeUnit.SECONDS)`.

Answer (score 1):

As already mentioned you need to use pool instead of take() also you can't use `Thread.interrupted();` to `interrupt` a `thread`. You need to use `Thread.currentThread().interrupt();`. Also, you do not need to check the time as `BlockingQueue#poll` do will wait for `2` seconds.

```
    while (!Thread.currentThread().isInterrupted()) {
        String x = q.poll(2, TimeUnit.SECONDS);
       if (x == null)
         System.out.println("No new message since two seconds, killing thread " + this.getName());
        Thread.currentThread().interrupt();
        System.out.println(x + "from " + this.getName());
    }
```

Output :

```
No new message since two seconds, killing thread Mango
Hello from Mango
No new message since two seconds, killing thread Apple
nullfrom Apple
No new message since two seconds, killing thread Banana
nullfrom Banana
```

Edit: However I believe you don't need a loop at all. Simply below code will works fine for you.

```
public void run() {
    try {
        String x = q.poll(2, TimeUnit.SECONDS);
        if (x == null)
          System.out.println("No new message since two seconds, killing thread " + this.getName());
        System.out.println(x + "from " + this.getName());
    } catch (InterruptedException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks, this solves the issue with killing the threads after two seconds. But I want to print hello from all threads before killing them after two seconds. How can we do this: Start all three threads > Print hello from all three > Have them listen for any new message for two seconds > Finally kill all three

Comment: @smaug What do you mean the printing `Hello` before killing the queue? If you want to supply message "Hello" to all the 3 thread then put "Hello" 2 more times in the queue.

Comment: Even then, it does not guarantee that all the "hello" messages are printed before any one of the threads is killed.

Comment: @smaug In that case, you need to make sure message are supplied to queue before your `Worker Threads` getting started. In your case put `queue.put("Hello ");` 3 times before the `for` loop where you have started worker thread.

Answer (score 1):

I just tried to do minimal fix on your code:

```
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.concurrent.ArrayBlockingQueue;
import java.util.concurrent.BlockingQueue;

public class Main {
    public static void main(String[] argv) throws Exception {
        int capacity = 10;
        BlockingQueue<String> queue = new ArrayBlockingQueue<String>(capacity);

        ArrayList<String> names = new ArrayList<String>();
        names.add("Apple"); names.add("Banana"); names.add("Mango");
        for (String name: names) {
            Worker a_worker = new Worker(queue);
            a_worker.setName(name);
            a_worker.start();
        }
        queue.put("Hello");
        queue.put("Bonjour");
    }
}

class Worker extends Thread {
    BlockingQueue<String> q;

    Worker(BlockingQueue<String> q) {
        this.q = q;
    }

    public void run() {
        long start = System.currentTimeMillis();
        long end = start + 2; //just wait for two milliseconds

        while (true) {
            String x = q.poll();
            if(x != null) {
                System.out.println(x + " from " + this.getName());
            } else if(System.currentTimeMillis() >= end){
                System.out.println("No new message since two milliseconds, killing thread " + this.getName());
                interrupt();
            }

            if(interrupted()) {
                break;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Sample Output:

```
Hello from Apple
No new message since two milliseconds, killing thread Banana
Bonjour from Mango
No new message since two milliseconds, killing thread Apple
No new message since two milliseconds, killing thread Mango
```